# Building and Deploying depending on front or backend changes in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm starting to use gitlab CI/CD pipeline but have some doubts regarding the output of the building process if i was to have a project(Repo) and inside this project I have the front and backend separated by the project structure, ex:

### CarProject

.gitlab-ci.yml

|__FrontEndCarProject

|__BackendCarProject

let's say that every time I change something in the frontend I would need to build it and deploy it to S3, but there is no need to build the backend (java application) and deploy it to elastic beanstalk (and vice versa for when i change the backend)..Is there a way to check where the changes have been made(FrontEndCarProject/BackendCarProject) using GitLab and redirect the .gitlab-ci.yml to a script file depending on if a have to deploy to S3 or elastic beanstalk?

Just trying

Note: another way is just to manually change the yml file depending on where i want to deploy..but is there a way to autodetect this and automated?

#### .gitlab-ci.yml

> > Just to get the idea, heres an example that would run in a linear way, but how can i  conditionally build/deploy(depending on my front or backend)? should i keep them in different repos for simplicity? is it a good practice?

```yaml
variables:
  ARTIFACT_NAME: cars-api-v$CI_PIPELINE_IID.jar
  APP_NAME: cars-api

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# ONLY Build when front(FrontendCarProject) in changed
build_front:
  stage: build
  image: Node:latest
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./dist

# ONLY build when backend(BackendCarProject) is changed
build_back:
  stage: build
  image: openjdk:12-alpine
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/libs/

# ONLY deploy when front(FrontendCarProject) in changed
deploy_s3:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - aws s3 cp ./build/libs/cars-api.jar s3://$S3_BUCKET/cars-api.jar

# ONLY deploy when backend(BackendCarProject) is changed
deploy_back_end:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: banst/awscli
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - aws s3 cp ./build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME s3://$S3_BUCKET/$ARTIFACT_NAME
    - aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APP_NAME --version-label $CI_PIPELINE_IID --source-bundle S3Bucket=$S3_BUCKET,S3Key=$ARTIFACT_NAME
    - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name $APP_NAME --environment-name "production" --version-label=$CI_PIPELINE_IID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your frontend and backend can be built and deployed seperately, than you can use [rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) to check if a change happened and [need:optional](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to only deploy the respective built libraries.

```
variables:
  ARTIFACT_NAME: cars-api-v$CI_PIPELINE_IID.jar
  APP_NAME: cars-api

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# ONLY Build when front(FrontendCarProject) in changed
build_front:
  stage: build
  image: Node:latest
  script:
    - npm install
  rules:
    - changes:
        - FrontEndCarProject/*
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./dist

# ONLY build when backend(BackendCarProject) is changed
build_back:
  stage: build
  image: openjdk:12-alpine
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
  rules:
    - changes:
        - BackendEndCarProject/*
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/libs/

# ONLY deploy when front(FrontendCarProject) in changed
deploy_s3:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - aws s3 cp ./build/libs/cars-api.jar s3://$S3_BUCKET/cars-api.jar
  needs:
    - job: build_front
      artifacts: true
      optional: true

# ONLY deploy when backend(BackendCarProject) is changed
deploy_back_end:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: banst/awscli
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - aws s3 cp ./build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME s3://$S3_BUCKET/$ARTIFACT_NAME
    - aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APP_NAME --version-label $CI_PIPELINE_IID --source-bundle S3Bucket=$S3_BUCKET,S3Key=$ARTIFACT_NAME
    - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name $APP_NAME --environment-name "production" --version-label=$CI_PIPELINE_IID
  needs:
    - job: build_back
      artifacts: true
      optional: true
```